# Python Graphframes: trouble installing dependencies

Tags: python, maven, apache-spark, pyspark, graphframes

I'm trying to run a [simple Graphframes example](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/graph-analysis/graphframes/user-guide-python.html). I have both Python 3.6.8 and Python 2.7.15, as well as Apache Maven 3.6.0, Java 1.8.0, Apache Spark 2.4.4 and Scala code runner version 2.11.12.

I got this error:

```
An error occurred while calling o58.loadClass.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graphframes.GraphFramePythonAPI
```

I tried to put [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40661407/6187682) in motion, but I became stuck on step 2.

I ran `pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11` and got the following output:

```
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Jul  9 2019, 16:51:35) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/jessica/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/jessica/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/spark/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
graphframes#graphframes added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-1be543dc-eac1-4324-bef5-4bab70bd9c95;1.0
    confs: [default]
downloading file:/home/jessica/.m2/repository/graphframes/graphframes/0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11/graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11.jar ..
    [SUCCESSFUL ] graphframes#graphframes;0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11!graphframes.jar (18ms)
downloading file:/home/jessica/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.16!slf4j-api.jar (13ms)
:: resolution report :: resolve 786773ms :: artifacts dl 67ms
    :: modules in use:
    graphframes#graphframes;0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.16 from spark-list in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   2   |   1   |   1   |   0   ||   2   |   2   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/graphframes/graphframes/0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11/graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11-sources.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

    Server access error at url https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/graphframes/graphframes/0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11/graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11-sources.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/graphframes/graphframes/0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11/graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11-src.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

    Server access error at url https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/graphframes/graphframes/0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11/graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11-src.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/graphframes/graphframes/0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11/graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11-javadoc.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

    Server access error at url https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/graphframes/graphframes/0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11/graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11-javadoc.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

    unknown resolver sbt-chain

    unknown resolver null


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-1a173e58-c356-43d7-9112-b06817ef3674
    confs: [default]
    2 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (411kB/27ms)
he19/10/25 10:39:01 WARN Utils: Your hostname, jessica-VirtualBox resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
19/10/25 10:39:01 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
lp19/10/25 10:39:02 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/tmp6pP3C_/connection6206654157170594455.info
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
    at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:138)
    at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(TempFileHelper.java:161)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Files.java:852)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer$.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Needless to say this is not the expected output, all of the links that timed out lead to 404s. My PC *is* behind a proxy, but the proxy settings are configured in the Maven settings files and I know that they work correctly.

Are there other proxy settings to change? Is there maybe another way to install these dependencies?

**EDIT**

I changed my `/usr/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json` file to:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python3",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11 --master local[10] pyspark-shell"
 },
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

then tried to run my Python script in a Jupyter Notebook. This did not work. In fact now it causes this error as soon as I run my Python script (after it has imported the required imports, it crashes)

**EDIT 2**

I tweaked my Firefox and downloaded the files myself.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jessica jessica   381110 Oct 22 12:17 graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jessica jessica     2541 Oct 22 12:14 graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11.pom
```

I then ran `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11.jar -DpomFile=graphframes-0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11.pom`, and though that procedure was successful, I still can't run my script (still for the same reason). However, there is now a `graphframes` folder in my maven repository that contains all the required files.

**EDIT 3**

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Jupyter, notebook, graphframes, toree, iPython and have added Anaconda - all for both Python 2.7 and Python 3. I could not install the Apache Toree kernel (v0.3.0) for Python/Pyspark (I do have SQL and Scala, apparently the Python/Pyspark kernel it is no longer supported - solutions for this are also welcomed).

My `SPARK_HOME=~/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7` variable has also been set, as well as `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, using [advice from this site](http://www.davidbaldin.com/hello-graphframe-in-py-spark/).

Long story short, put the jars straight in `$SPARK_HOME/jars`

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same thing you are seeing. The problem is that the repository `bintray` that hosted the artifacts [shut down on May 2021](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/384). When you specify the Maven coordinates for graphframes, you should also [provide the current repository](https://datacadamia.com/db/spark/pyspark/pyspark) that hosts this artifact.

Executing PySpark as follow worked for me.

```
pyspark \
    --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark2.4-s_2.11 \
    --repositories https://repos.spark-packages.org
```

Answer (score 1):

Furthering jane-wayne's answer.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .master('yarn')
    .appName('GraphFrames_Test')
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark2.4-s_2.11")
    .config("spark.jars.repositories", "https://repos.spark-packages.org")
    .getOrCreate()
    )
```